# Node.js + express + regex paths, on page refreshes node.js doesn't send a responce

Tags: regex, node.js, express

When using the following route:

```
app.get(/\/api\/core\/(c|humanities)/gi, function(req, res) {
  res.send("HI");
});
```

On the first page load I get the proper 'hi' response.  But after a few page refreshes I'll get 404 errors stating:

> Cannot GET /api/core/c

The regex is supposed to match `/api/core/c` and `/api/core/humanities` as well as be case insensitive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Found out the issue, it was the 'g' flag.

Comment: You can post an answer.